# TL084CN Unexpected Output

Tags: operational-amplifier

Want to get binary Pin 7 output (0V or 3.3V), dependent on light intensity on the photoresistor. But the output is not as expected.

I have built the circuit below with the help of LF33ABV 3.3V voltage regulator. Using 9V battery as the main power source (those elements not shown). Have added the pin connection numbers of TL084CN in the figure.

[image: TL084CN circuit]

Here are the outputs, when I play with the light intensity. (Made the measurements with a multimeter)

Pin 5: 1.64V, Pin 6: 1.23V, Pin 7: 2.58V; (was expecting Pin 7 railed to 3.3V)
Pin 5: 1.64V, Pin 6: 2.20V, Pin 7: 1.33V; (was expecting Pin 7 railed to 0V)

Is there a mistake that attract your attention? Thanks

[TL084CN data sheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000493.pdf)

Comment: Did you have a look at the output swing specs in the datasheet?

Comment: You want an actual comparator here, not an op amp.

Comment: You are both correct. Thanks alot. Will replace the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a VDD of 3.3V, you're running the op-amp below the minimum rated voltage of 6V. See this chart from the datasheet:

[image]

Additionally, the TL084 isn't a rail-to-rail output, which means that you wouldn't get exactly 0V when the op-amp is saturated low.

Comment: The TL084 is old school (what was then) high speed technology. They need a generous supply range and draw quite a bit of current.

Answer (score 1):

First, this device is not rated for use below 6V (minimum) across the power pins.

Second, the output of this device cannot approach the power rail more closely than about 1.5V (see datasheet page 6 for maximum Vio vs. Vpower).

In all probability, the internal bias circuits are not fully powered because they have not been fed sufficient power and the output is stuck at the closest to the negative rail it can get.

If you really want a true 'low', I would suggest using either a rail to rail device or a comparator that is rated for operation on a single supply of 3.3V (they are available in abundance).

A better solution would be an instrumentation amplifier followed by a comparator, which will give precision and repeatability.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Supply voltage range of chosen opamp:[image]

It is also not rail to rail output one. You would be better with [this](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MCP6001UT-I%2FOT/MCP6001UT-I%2FOTTR-ND/562450) one or similar one.

[This](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NCX2200.pdf) one is rail to rail input/ouput **comparator**.

Answer (score 1):

The change in resistance on a photoresistor is not a subtle thing, especially if you're looking for a light on/off transition.

If you're not looking for subtle modulations, Lose the wheatstone bridge, use a standard comparator circuit (powered appropriately), and use a voltage divider with a pot to control the threshold voltage.